# How can I set auto-scroll for a QtGui.QTextEdit in PyQt4?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

So, I have a `QtGui.QTextEdit` that will be dynamically inserted with plain text based on what the user enters to some other `QtGui.QLineEdit`. As the user enters text into the `QLineEdit`, the user would at some point in time need to scroll down to see the latest data.

Is it possible to set an auto-scroll to the `QTextEdit` (which is just read only, if it matters) so that it is automatically scrolls down to display the latest data entered by the user? If yes, how?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean "how to auto scroll with QTextEdit"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when signal `QLineEdit::textEdited` is emitted, append the text in `QLineEdit` to `QTextEdit`, and then:

```
QTextCursor c =  txtedit.textCursor();
c.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);
txtedit.setTextCursor(c);
// txtedit.ensureCursorVisible(); // you might need this also
```

[reference here.](http://www.qtforum.org/article/13274/auto-scroll-with-qtextedit.html)